# Column Name beginning with a number?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column name in one of my tables called: `3RD_DIAG_CODE - VARCHAR2 (10 Byte)`

When I try to run a query, it gives me the following error highlighting `3RD_DIAG_CODE`.

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.

How can I bring this field in without it throwing an error every time I bring this field in?

Comment: Not enough information, post your entire query.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using column names that start with a number then you need to use double quotes. For example:

```
create table foo (
"3RD_DIAG_CODE" varchar2(10 byte) --make sure you use uppercase for variable name
);

insert into foo values ('abc');
insert into foo values ('def');
insert into foo values ('ghi');
insert into foo values ('jkl');
insert into foo values ('mno');
commit;

select * from foo;

3RD_DIAG_C
----------
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno

select 3RD_DIAG_CODE from foo;

RD_DIAG_CODE
------------
       3
       3
       3
       3
       3

select "3RD_DIAG_CODE" from foo;

3RD_DIAG_C
----------
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
```

**Edit:** As for the error message itself, you are probably (as BQ wrote) missing a comma from the select clause.

Comment: Regardless, if your variable name is in upper case it requires double quotes.  Didn't know it worked for leading numbers, too.

Answer (score 3):

Check your specification, but in SQL Server we would have to enclose that column name in square brackets:  `[3RD_DIAG_CODE]`

Comment: By putting double quotes around my field name, I was able to have the query run and give me the results I needed.

Ex: 

        SELECT 
        Fieldnames, 
        "3RD_DIAG_CODE" as DiagCd3
    
    From MyTable;

Comment: The OP has indicated they are using Oracle, so solutions providing SQL Server syntax aren't helpful. On StackOverflow the `[sql]` tag just means the query language and not MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have two columns listed without a comma between them.

```
create table t (id number primary key, 3d varchar2(30))
Error at Command Line:1 Column:39
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"


create table t (id number primary key, "3d" varchar2(30));
table T created.
desc t
Name Null     Type         
---- -------- ------------ 
ID   NOT NULL NUMBER       
3d            VARCHAR2(30) 


> select id, 3d from t --[as @gsiem mentions: THIS IS BAD]
ID                     3D       
---------------------- -------- 

> select id, "3d" from t
ID                     3d                             
---------------------- ------------------------------ 

> select id, [3d] from t

Error starting at line 7 in command:
select id, [3d] from t
Error at Command Line:7 Column:11
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
> select id 3d from t

Error starting at line 8 in command:
select id 3d from t
Error at Command Line:8 Column:10
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Try adding a row or two of data to the table and re-run your selects-- selecting 3d vs. "3d" behave differently.

Comment: @gsiems, interesting. Didn't expect that behavior at all. > select 3dxasdfasdf, 4adffafafdasdf from dual
XASDFASDF ADFFAFAFDASDF 
--------- ------------- 
3.0       4