# Can I use column name as a parameter in case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to use the column name's value as a parameter in a case statement.

The column names I have are numbers and I want to do some calculations on the column name and return [value] or [null] depending on the results.

I am doing this in a view on SQL Server.

so for example, lets say 2013 is the name of the column and year([some date]) = 2016 then [New Column] should equal to 0.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN [2013] < year([some date]) then 0 else [2013] END AS [New Column]
```

Comment: sure you can ...

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here. sample data as DDL+DML and desired results would make this question much easier to understand.

Comment: My question is that I want to use the value of the column name as a parameter in the case statement. So the Column's name would be 2013

Comment: The bigger question is, why would you *want* to do this?

Comment: So, in your example, where you say [2013], you want it to have the number 2013 rather than the value of a column named [2013]?

Comment: Yes, the number 2013.

Comment: What's the use case?

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but why don't you just write 2013 instead of [2013] ?

Comment: @david because `2013` is a number, and `[2013]` is an entity name, in this case a column name (or at least that’s the intention).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible: [T-SQL documentation about case statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Naming your column name as a number looks a bit dirty though, I would advise against that. That might actually be your issue. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114193/column-name-beginning-with-a-number)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments to the question, you're looking for something like this (**Pseudo code - Will not work!**):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CAST(NAME_OF([2013]) AS INT) < year([some date]) THEN 0 ELSE [2013] END AS [New Column]
FROM [TableName]
```

Where the **pseudo function** `NAME_OF` returns the name of the object.
However, SQL Server does not contain such a function (It does have `object_name`, but that takes in an int that represents the object's id, and to get the object id you need to know the object's name, so that doesn't help very much, and anyway table columns don't have an object id, their id is a combination of their containing table id and their column id).

You could do something like this, though:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 2013 < year([some date]) THEN 0 ELSE [2013] END AS [New Column]
FROM [TableName]
```

That would return 0 when `[some date]` is before 2013, or the value stored in the column named `2013` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on Zohar Peled's roundup, I can think of a way. Especially since you also selected the tag tsql...

```
declare @colname nvarchar(4) = '2013'
declare @statement nvarchar(4000) = N'SELECT CASE WHEN ' + @colname + N' < year([some date]) then 0 else [' + @colname + N'] END AS [New Column]'
exec sp_executesql @statement
```

I have to admit though, I do not understand (either) what you are trying to do... This way you have to hard-code the column names anyway, which raises the question why you didn't do that from the start.